# Bing Map Windows Phone 8.1 URL Schema

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing Windows Phone 8.1 app and  doing everything right but bing map doing exactly nothing, I am calling bing map on my program. In this damn link

[Bing Map URL Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx)

samples says "you can parse 2 or more paramaters to add pushpin to map".

For example if I call Launcher with this

```
bingmaps:?collection=point.36.116584_-115.176753_Caesars%20Palace~point.36.113126_-115.175188_The%20Bellagio
```

but it add only 1 pushpin which is a head point on url. I must see 2 pushpins on bing map, must I?

What am I wrong? My test code is here:

```
string a = "bingmaps:?collection=point.36.116584_-115.176753_Caesars%20Palace~point.36.113126_-115.175188_The%20Bellagio&lvl=16&cp=36.114902~-115.176669";
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(a));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you are referring to is for Windows 8/8.1 and not for Windows Phone 8.1. WP8.1 has just started adding in this functionality and not all features are supported yet. You can find the WP8.1 specific documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614996.aspx

If you look near the bottom there are some examples of unsupported options. One of them is "Collections that include more than one element."